# How do I create equilavance classes for my Hangman 2 App in swift 2?

Tags: swift

I'm making a evul hangman app with swift 2. Evul hangman is a game where the computer is cheating on the user. With normal hangman the computer chooses a word and it will hold on to this word. With evul hangman the computer won't choose a word but will keep a list of all posibilities. Every time the user guesses it will try to hold on to the biggest list with possibilties. http://nifty.stanford.edu/2011/schwarz-evil-hangman/ for more information.

Every time the user guesses it's my job to group all words together who share the same properties. For example the user guesses the letter "e" for the first time. The word is 45 letters long. This leaves me with 5 equilavence classes:

E _ _ _, 
_ E _ _, 
_ _ E _, 
_ _ _ E, 
_ E E _,

This is just an example. The property _ E E _ could have been possible too.

My idea was to create a dictionary where the key is propery/indexes and where the value is the list of words sharing that property. But in swift 2 this is not possible because key's dont conform to the hashable protocol. I'm using a list of indexes as key.

If my question is not described clear enough dont hesitate to ask and I will edit it. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you create your own Key that implements the hashable protocol?

Comment: That could be an option but I'm guessing there's a better option out there.

Comment: Why do you believe there's a better option? Is there any reason that making the key hashable is particularly difficult?

Comment: Because it's a common exercise on universities and I don't think they expect us to implement the hashable protocol. But I'm gonna find out how to implement the hasable protocol.